# How to resize the plotted frame in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot([0,1],[1,0])
plt.show()
```

I would like to be able to resize just the plot itself, NOT the entire window, without having to physically resize it. For example, I would like to have the x axis be only 0.75 times as long as it currently is and the y-axis be only 0.5 times long. Remember, I'm just talking about the plotted part itself, not the entire window. But how?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are looking for is the GridSpec function in the matplotlib module.

you can use :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_ticklabels_invisible(fig):
   for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
      ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
   for tl in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
      tl.set_visible(False)


plt.figure(0)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1, 2), rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 0))
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 1))

plt.suptitle("subplot2grid")
make_ticklabels_invisible(plt.gcf())
plt.show()
```

which will return us the following example :

[image]

for further information you can visit [this link](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)

Comment: OK, but I'm not trying to generate multiple subplots. I just want to get one plot with specified dimensions.

Comment: I understood what you are looking for. I suggested that you will create one major subplot and edit the dimensions as you like over the frame grid. for example I gave you the image that shows you can control the size of each plot.